Make a Shapekey Driver Taper to 0 Once it's Reached 1
I've been trying to have a shapekey controlled by a driver taper back down to zero once it's reached it's max value of 1, but having a lot of trouble getting anything to work...not too familiar with coding at all so any kind of expressions I've found never seem to work or I can't get them to work how I want.
I saw another thread here that was almost right, but I can't get it to taper back immediately after reach 1. Maybe I'm being dense, but does anyone know how to achieve this?
Thank you for your time!

It would be helpful to see what you have tried & how you increase the value, and what the expected values are. Example: 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0( or 1?), 0.2 (or 0?), ... the modulo operator can do the "reset to 0", e.g. c = c % 1 so c will be in the range of 0 and 1, excluding the 1.

Mostly the expression from here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104526/how-do-i-get-a-driver-variable-to-taper-down-to-0-once-the-variable-is-doubled
Since it seemed the most promising, but it doesn't behave how I would think (or I just don't understand how it works).
It does the tapering, but only after the value is doubled, like the poster wants. messing with the numbers myself, from just changes the values to 1s/0s, with any number of decimals in between or negative numbers, swapping the < >, I can't seem to get it to do what I want

Drivers have f-Curves, so sometimes it's more convenient to avoid the maths. Would something like this be relevant?

I can't seem to open that file. Blender just crashes when trying.
