# Add Min and Max Values to Driver Expression?

Tags: drivers

I have a driver using a scripted expression: var*2. It's working great but the values it's outputting range from .005 up to about 1.5. I'd like to limit the range of the output to something like a minimum of .5 to a maximum of 1.25. Is it possible to do this within the expression itself?

Edit: A little more information, I'm trying to use a sound file to drive a particle value. "Bake Sound to F-Curves" provides me with a non editable F-curve so I'm trying to use a driver to increase the amplitude of the baked F-Curve.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/whats-the-range-of-values-on-a-sound-baked-f-curve

Comment: Thanks, I had looked over that. I'm just wondering if there's a simple expression that can be written that sets a min and max value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Min max**

Use the expression `min(max(v, 0.5), 1.25)` or its dual `max(0.5, min(v, 1.25))` where v is the driver variable (sound curve value)

```
>>> v = 0.05
>>> min(max(v, 0.5), 1.25)
0.5

>>> v = 3
>>> min(max(v, 0.5), 1.25)
1.25

>>> v = 1.1
>>> min(max(v, 0.5), 1.25)
1.1
```

If you wish to double the variable `v` simply replace `v` with `2 * v` in expression.

I would recommend you normalize the values in some way [What's the range of values on a sound-baked f-curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/whats-the-range-of-values-on-a-sound-baked-f-curve)

Related

[How to set driver distance max and min influence?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73109/how-to-set-driver-distance-max-and-min-influence)